# Parametrization of $ax^2+bxy+c=0$

Tags: diophantine-equations, quadratics

Can I just fix $y=t$ and use quadratic formula to get the rational points of the diophantine $$ax^2+bxy+c=0?$$ or is there another method? I feel like I am turning in circles with the quadratic formula.

Comment: "Cardano's formula" usually refers to the solution of a cubic equation. I see no cubic in your problem. What do you mean by "Cardano's formula"?

Comment: Sorry. my mistake.I meant quadratic formula.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the quadratic formula to solve for $x$ and use that to set conditions on $y$?

Comment: Something along this line: $(2ax+by)^2=(by)^2-4ac$ So I guess i am going to suppose that $(by)^2-4ac=u^2$. I already know what $u$ is. $u=2ax+by$ Does this really help solve the problem?

Comment: I don't see how that helps. You did complete the square, but what you are solving for is not clear. Try solving for $x$ with the usual quadratic formula (or completing the square). The expression inside the square root must be a square, so that gives one requirement. The complete expression, ending with division by $2a$, gives another requirement. But frankly, with three unknown coefficients, I don't see how you could get a good complete answer.

Comment: I think they are totally equivalent. So let me rewrite the expression as: $(x+ \frac{by}{2a})^2= \frac{(by)^2-4ac}{4a^2}$. I have to assume that $(by)^2-4ac= k(2au)^2$ Where do I go from there? By the way, i am looking for the couples $(x,y)$. Please feel free to jot down your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Not quite. I see that $(by)^2-4ac=k^2$ (the numerator in your right-hand fraction). Also, $2ax=by \pm k$. I am not sure how to put them together into one requirement. If you had more information on $a$, $b$, or $c$ we could go more easily.

Comment: That's right. Truth is the quadratic method must not be the right method. There is enough info to find all the solutions. You know it too.